# getTitle() returning current URL instead of page title

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario like clicking on the images of home page and validating page title. I am facing an issue say I am using the `getTitle()` function to get a page title to validate but it's returning the current URL, so my test case failed by comparing with the page title.

Here's my question: Why is it returning a current URL instead of a page title? If anyone faced this issue.

Note : This does not occur every time.

Comment: Is your page fully loaded when you're getting the URL?

Comment: Add the html (title part) to your question.

Comment: No, I think page is not completly loaded @ FDM

Comment: Check Locator used. it looks issue with used locator.use another locator and try it.

Comment: Hello @Chetan Patel , I didn't get your point . Bcoz Is it need to use any locator in calling getTitle() function .If I am wrong in understanding  your point please elaborate you answer with an example

Comment: Hi Sunil - does it fix the problem if you add an explicit wait to make sure the page loads completely before you check the page title?

Comment: Why dont you try using `By.tagName("title")`?

Comment: First of all .gettitle() is method not a function , can you please share page URL where you are trying?

Comment: Does it happen for every page or only for some of them?

Comment: Hello @dzieciou, it happens for only some times .In the remaining times it is giving title only

Comment: Hello @vincebowdren , it is not resolved, still some times I can see the returning url instead of page title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `getTitle()`, try the below:

```
WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.tagName("title"));
System.out.println(title.getText());
```

Comment: Here a small change in the above  syntax

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName("title")).getInnerHtml().then(
function(text){
            console.log(text,"TEXT");
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl="http://www.google.com";
    String expectedTitle="Google";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String actualTitle=driver.getTitle();
    if(actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle)){
        System.out.println("Test Pass");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }
```

it is working fine get the page Title in String and then Compare it with your Actual Title and if that matches then Test Pass

Comment: How does this solve the problem of getTitle() sometimes returning the page URL?

Comment: no it will Not return the Page URL i am using selenium 2.42 and Mozilla 28 Version.